# How to print fields with numeric names in mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with numbers as field names.

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5d8bae78577c111a86605d39"),
      "subject" : "ABAD001",
      "10" : 1556.9,
      "30" : 1325.94
    }
```

I can't print the "numeric" field

```
 db.collection.findOne().10
```

This is the error:

```
[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

How I could access the "numeric" fields?

I tried

```
db.collection.findOne().['10']
```

But it does not work

Comment: You can try something like this in the shell to get the first document that has a field key of "10" - `db.collection.findOne({"10":{$exists: true}})`. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: `db.collection.findOne()['10']`. You did not need the **"dot"**.